Cloning classes with obj.__index = self in lua. Why do we need the other one?
I saw a lot of coders do this when init new table, set __index to itself. Why?
  local Backpack = {}
  Backpack.__index = Backpack

To clone we still use obj.__index = self So why do we need the second line? Does it do something I don't understand?
    local Backpack = {}
    -- why we need this?
    Backpack.__index = Backpack
    Backpack.initial = "Water, cloths"
    function Backpack.new()
        local obj = {}
        -- If we have this?
        obj.__index = self
        return obj
        end
    
    local AlexBackpack = Backpack:new()
    AlexBackpack.initial = "Water, cloths, knife, fire starter"
    
    -- Backpack.initial:    Water, cloths
    -- AlexBackpack.initial:    Water, cloths, knife, fire starter
    print('Backpack.initial:', Backpack.initial)
    print('AlexBackpack.initial:', AlexBackpack.initial)

Check this code online https://onecompiler.com/lua/42fqg7s34

The code you showed is totally wrong, or did you omit any important part?

@shingo why is it wrong? it works https://onecompiler.com/lua/42fqg7s34 what I am missing? =(

Removing the 2 lines also works, and self is not defined.

@shingo yes it works... this is why I wonder why people use it...

People don't use it like this, they use setmetatable, that's why I think you omitted something.

@shingo ok so if I change function Backpack.new() to function Backpack:new(), print(AlexBackpack.__index) works... but still why do we need the second line in the code? what are the use cases.....

Talking about
local Backpack = {}
Backpack.__index = Backpack

Backpack.__index = Backpack

simply stores the table Backpack in itself at index __index
This on its own does nothing useful.
As already mentioned
function Backpack.new()
  local obj = {}
  obj.__index = self
  return obj
end

is also not very helpful as self is nil and assigning nil to obj.__index does not do anything in this context.
First of all we replace  function Backpack.new() with function Backpack.new(self) or short function Backpack:new() so self refers to Backpack if we call it with Backpack.new(Backpack) or short Backpack:new()
Then obj the new instance of our class Backpack we are about to create needs access to Backpack
This is done using a metatable.
function Backpack.new()
  local obj = {}
  setmetatable(obj, self) -- this is new
  obj.__index = self
  return obj
end

Now obj's metatable is new and as metamethod __index refers to Backpack Lua will always default to indexing Backpack whenever that index does not exist in obj.
Otherwise you would have to implement each method and property in every instance of your class.
From the manual:

__index: The indexing access operation table[key]. This event happens when table is not a table or when key is not present in table. The
metavalue is looked up in the metatable of table.



Self is not defined in functions that are structured with periods, you're supposed to use setmetable to define a backpack with its own table
You use __index for OOP (Object Oriented Programming), read up on that to refine your code

